# Fetch the record sorting on two fields by largest value criteria using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have below two records in my input with BEGDA and ENTRY both of which are numeric values. I was fetch the record that has the greatest BEGDA and the ENTRY values. I am trying to sort on both the fields but it seems like it is picking the first one from the group when the BEGDA matches

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <E1PITYP>
        <PLVAR>01</PLVAR>
        <OTYPE>P</OTYPE>
        <OBJID>EMPLOYEE-6-51</OBJID>
        <INFTY>0002</INFTY>
        <BEGDA>20180607</BEGDA>
        <ENTRY>201806071133452850700</ENTRY>
        <ENDDA>99991231</ENDDA>
        <E1P0002>
            <PERNR>EMPLOYEE-6-51</PERNR>
            <INFTY>0002</INFTY>
            <ENDDA>99991231</ENDDA>
            <BEGDA>20180607</BEGDA>
            <INITS>TH</INITS>
            <NACHN>Hire</NACHN>
            <VORNA>Test</VORNA>
            <MIDNM/>
            <ANRED/>
            <GESCH>2</GESCH>
            <GBDAT>19900605</GBDAT>
            <NATIO>GB</NATIO>
            <PERID/>
        </E1P0002>
    </E1PITYP>
    <E1PITYP>
        <PLVAR>01</PLVAR>
        <OTYPE>P</OTYPE>
        <OBJID>EMPLOYEE-6-51</OBJID>
        <INFTY>0002</INFTY>
        <BEGDA>20180607</BEGDA>
        <ENTRY>201806071137058230700</ENTRY>
        <ENDDA>99991231</ENDDA>
        <E1P0002>
            <PERNR>EMPLOYEE-6-51</PERNR>
            <INFTY>0002</INFTY>
            <ENDDA>99991231</ENDDA>
            <BEGDA>20180607</BEGDA>
            <INITS>TH</INITS>
            <NACHN>Hire</NACHN>
            <VORNA>Test</VORNA>
            <MIDNM/>
            <ANRED/>
            <GESCH>2</GESCH>
            <GBDAT>19900605</GBDAT>
            <NATIO>GB</NATIO>
            <PERID>AA888888A</PERID>
        </E1P0002>
    </E1PITYP>

</root>
```

My xslt is below, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please advise experts.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="E1PITYP[INFTY = '0002']" group-by="BEGDA">
            <xsl:sort select="BEGDA" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="ENTRY" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized in my case BEGDA may duplicate but ENTRY wont so it is sensible to group by ENTRY or "."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="E1PITYP[INFTY = '0002']" group-by="ENTRY">
            <xsl:sort select="BEGDA" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="ENTRY" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet
```

>

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="E1PITYP[INFTY = '0002']" group-by=".">
            <xsl:sort select="BEGDA" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="ENTRY" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```